# Hibernate: where clause in left join is not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, left-join, where-clause

I have 2 classes in a one-to-many relationship:

```
   Class Competition{
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="competition")   
        public Set<Event> getEvents() {
            return events;
        }
    }
    Class Event{
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id_competition")
        public Competition getCompetition() {
            return competition;
        }
    }
```

When I run the query below I receive more data then it should. In the database, I have a competition entry, lets call it c1, and 3 events: e1, e2 and e3. One of the events does not meet the condition (e1 has the stardate < '2013-09-13') but when I run the query I get 3 events instead of only 2. I am sure about the data in the database, so what's the problem with the **where clause** ?

`"select com from Competition as com inner join com.events event where event.expectedStartdate > '2013-09-13' "`

Also, I must specify that if I delete the 2 events that meet the condition and keep the one that does not meet the condition, the query returns nothing (no object Competition).

I also tried the `with` clause but I get the same result.

Comment: What happens when you run the query from an interactive DB UI?  Also, you haven't said which database you're using.

Comment: Try removing `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` and running the query, you are telling hibernate to load all child objects.

Comment: @Jim Garrison I am using mysql. I will edit my post to put details about running the query in the DB UI.

Comment: @Sachin Thapa From what I know is that EAGER (or LAZY) only specifies the time when the collection is loaded and nothing more.

Comment: The return type of your query is an entity, when the entity is found, you get the *entire* entity.  Do not think of it as merely mapping SQL result sets onto value objects.  That's not how it works!

Comment: Thanks @Affe for adding more clarification, also when you delete two rows condition is not met so `Competition` itself is not loaded, so you get nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query for an entity you are always going to receive the fully realized object mapping back.  You cannot filter out what goes into the set of events by putting conditions on the query like that.  If the query finds a `Competition` then you get the entire competition.  The Competition is always going to have all of its children in there when you access the Set.

Put another way that ORM query translates to plain language as:

"Find me every competition that has at least one event that starts after the 13th"

*not*

"Find me every competition and only include events if they start after the 13th."

Comment: I am interested in: 

"Find me every competition that has at least one event that starts after the 13th and fetch me those events that start after 13th". 

Isn't this possible?

Comment: Sure, make the return type of the query the events?  Returning a "partial" entity is kind of nonsense in the grand scheme of things.  If it returned you a Competition with only a partial list of children, it would then also be obligated to delete the ones that you didn't include when the session synchronizes......

Comment: Ok, I will think at another approach and come back with feedback.